# Unity 5 : Animator: Não consigo excluir.

Tags: unity3d

Boa noite . 
Eu estou desenvolvendo um jogo seguindo um vídeo tutorial, no tutorial só tem o **Any State**, mas quando eu crio,  no meu aparece o **Entry** e o **Exit** e eu não estou conseguindo exclui-los. É possível excluir ? E porque no meu apareceu diferente do tutorial ?

Segue a imagem para melhor compreensão. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu imagino que você esteja seguindo um tutorial do Unity 4, no Unity 5 é impossível deletar esses estados.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele.

Comment: @CesarMiguel, por que não fornece a resposta? Ele perguntou se era possível excluir, eu disse que não e que tá diferente do tutorial por ser uma versão diferente da unity...

Comment: só me parece que a tua resposta devia ser transformada em comentário, só por estares a supor qual o tutorial que ele está a seguir, sem assim conseguir dar uma resposta concreta, foi apenas por isso

Comment: @CesarMiguel, mas essa é a resposta. Responde as duas perguntas do AP... Que não é possível e que a causa provável da diferença são as versões do software.

Comment: Certo, justificado :) Apenas foi o que me pareceu ao fazer a análise.